# T-SQL query for getting the sum of active datasets per day if I have start and end date for every dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the following SQL Server database table with a starting and end date for every dataset:

| Task | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FirstTask | 2022-12-02 | 2022-12-06 |
| SecondTask | 2022-12-03 | 2022-12-06 |
| ThirdTask | 2022-12-06 | 2022-12-07 |

Now I am looking for a query which gives me for every date between the lowest start and the highest end date the number of active tasks for every day:

| Day | NumberOfActiveTasks |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02 | 1 |
| 2022-12-03 | 2 |
| 2022-12-04 | 2 |
| 2022-12-05 | 2 |
| 2022-12-06 | 3 |
| 2022-12-07 | 1 |

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I guess with the standard SQL functions I can not do this :-(

Comment: If you don't have one, invest in a calendar table; then this becomes trivial as you can just `JOIN` to your table above from/to the calendar table and  aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, use your Calendar Table. If you don't have one, invest in one. There are 100's (possibly 1,000's) of articles out there on how to both create and populate one, so I'm not going to cover that here, and every person's/business' calender table tends to a "little" different for bespoke needs.

Once you have your Calender table, you can just `JOIN` to it and then aggregate on the calendar date:

```sql
SELECT CT.CalendarDate,
       COUNT(*) AS ActiveTasks
FROM (VALUES('FirstTask','2022-12-02','2022-12-06'),
            ('SecondTask','2022-12-03','2022-12-06'),
            ('ThirdTask','2022-12-06','2022-12-07'))V(Task,StartDate,EndDate)
     JOIN dbo.CalendarTable CT ON CT.CalendarDate BETWEEN V.StartDate AND V.EndDate
GROUP BY CT.CalendarDate
ORDER BY CT.CalendarDate;
```